# Since upgrading to ArcGIS 10, my application doesn't rescale the map when the window is resized

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, .net, scale, arcgis-10.3

I am upgrading a .NET application from ArcGIS 9.3 to ArcGIS 10.3. I've noticed that the map control behaves differently: the map no longer automatically rescales itself when the window is resized. To put it another way, **when you resize the map the scale stays the same even though the extent changes**. I would rather that the map rescaled when the window is resized, as it did under ArcGIS 9.3.

The commentary below from ESRI explains that this change is **by design**.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_s_new_for_map_display_and_navigation/00qp0000001w000000/

> **Less redrawing in data view**
>
> In previous versions of ArcMap, if you changed the size of the ArcMap
>   display while working in data view, either by resizing the ArcMap
>   window or by docking/undocking/resizing a dockable window, *by default
>   your map was completely redrawn to fit inside the available display
>   area*. So the scale changed and the extent stayed the same (although
>   you may have seen some extra geographic coverage based on how well the
>   extent fit inside the new shape of the display area). *At version 10,
>   the default drawing behavior in data view has been changed* so that
>   when the display size is changed, your map is no longer completely
>   redrawn to fit inside the display. Instead, the scale stays the same
>   and the extent will change. If you make the display bigger, you'll see
>   a larger geographic extent, and vice versa.
>
> This has the performance advantage that the portion of the display
>   unaffected by resizing doesn't need to be redrawn at all. For example,
>   if you close a docked window, only the portion of the display that was
>   obscured by the window needs to be redrawn. It is also easier to work
>   with the display because geographic features on your map don't move
>   around as you dock and undock windows. Features on your map remain in
>   the same location in the display until you manually pan or zoom the
>   map.

**In summary**: I want the ArcGIS 10 map in my .NET application to rescale when the window is resized, just as it did under ArcGIS 9.3.

Comment: @Dan-Jurgella Yes, it is interesting that even the option in ArcMap was removed. So in fact the new 'default' behaviour is the **only** behaviour.

Comment: Ah sorry, I had deleted my comment after I saw that you had reiterated in the original post that it was by design. Bacically I had also pointed out that they removed the option, which I also think is very unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IScreenDisplay interface has a ScaleContents property; set it to True and the old behavior is back.

```vb
My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.ScaleContents = True
```

This works as a button click event in ArcMap, though I'll probably create an extension that the user can enable or disable. Hopefully it will also work in your application.

Comment: I'd +100 this if I could - very helpful intervention, thank you. Works very nicely for me.

Comment: For me, the line of code would read: `mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.ScaleContents = True`.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is resized at runtime, the `PageLayoutControl` and `MapControl` do not automatically resize. To resize the controls so that they always fill the extent of the form, anchor the controls to the form.

[image]

If the `PageLayoutControl` or `MapControl` contains a lot of data, redrawing this data while the form is resized can be computationally costly. To increase performance, suppress the data redraw until the resizing is complete. During the resize, a stretched bitmap is drawn instead.

```cs
    private void MapViewer_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Suppress data redraw and draw bitmap instead.
        axMapControl1.SuppressResizeDrawing(true, 0);
        axPageLayoutControl1.SuppressResizeDrawing(true, 0);
    }


    private void MapViewer_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //Stop bitmap draw and draw data.
        axMapControl1.SuppressResizeDrawing(false, 0);
        axPageLayoutControl1.SuppressResizeDrawing(false, 0);}
```

[See also AxMapControl painting issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135952/workaround-for-axmapcontrol-painting-issue-only-problematic-at-certain-screen-r/136398#136398)

Comment: Thank you @Farid-Cher. However the issue I am having is that while the map control **does** resize (it is anchored properly :-) ), the map does not rescale itself. What I want is for the map to automatically rescale when resizing as it does with ArcGIS 9.3. If you create a simple application with a map control on 9.3 and on 10(.x), and place them alongside each other, you can see the difference in behaviour. I'll add a clarifying comment to my question.

Comment: Check the updated answer.